# Database Design - Need help scaling query

Tags: database, design-patterns, database-design, nosql, amazon-dynamodb

I'm trying to find the best data-structure/data store solution (highest performance) for the following request:

I have a list of attributes that I need to store for all individual in the US, for example:

```
+------------+-------+-------------+
| Attribute  | Value |     SSN     |
+------------+-------+-------------+
| hair color | black | 123-45-6789 |
| eye color  | brown | 123-45-6789 |
| height     | 175   | 123-45-6789 |
| sex        | M     | 123-45-6789 |
| shoe size  | 42    | 123-45-6789 |
```

As you can guess, with the general population, there are nothing unique and identifiable from those attributes.
However, let's assume that if we were to fetch from a combination of 3 or 4 attributes, then I would be able to uniquely identify a person (find their SSN).

Now here's the difficulties, the set of combinations that can uniquely identify a person will evolve over time and be adjusted.

What would be my best bet for storing and querying the data with the scenario mentioned above, that will remain highly performant (<100ms) at scale?

Current attempt with combining two attributes:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM people WHERE hair='black') p1 
JOIN (SELECT * FROM people WHERE height=175) p2 
ON p1.SSN = p2.SSN
```

But with a database with millions of rows, as you can guess.. NOT performant.

Thank you!

Comment: just wondering, but can you switch to a Document DB?

Comment: Hi @DavidGuida, thanks for your answer. I could totally switch to document DB.
The data store solution isn't the constraint, high performance is what matters.

Do you have any suggestions on how you would design the document?

Answer (score 0):

if the data store is not a constraint, I would use a DocumentDB, something like MongoDB, CosmosDB or even ElasticSearch.

With Mongo, for example, you could leverage its schemaless nature and have a collection of People with one property per "attribute":

```
{
  "SSN": "123-45-6789",
  "eyeColor": "brown",
  "hairColor" "blond",
  "sex": "M"
}
```

documents in this collection *might* have different properties, but it's not an issue. All you have to do now is to put an index on each one and run your queries.